# Signature Key Generation for AWS S3 HTTP Post

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having problems generating a valid signature key for doing HTTP Post in browser- I keep getting errors like

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

and since that doesn't tell me anything much about where the problem lies, i decided to debug if my signature calculation method is correct.

So I decided to replicate the example [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) using the given **String to sign** and the **Secret Access Key**. My generated signature doesn't match the signature given on the documentation page.

What am I doing wrong here ? The below is my existing code (I am using AWS Signature V4)

```
     private void debugSignatureGeneration() throws Exception {

        byte[] testSigningKey = getSigningKey("wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY", "20151229", "us-east-1",
                "s3");
        String testStringToSign = "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";
        String testSignature = getSignatureV4(testStringToSign, testSigningKey);
        System.out.println("test signature " + testSignature);
    }


static String getSignatureV4(String stringToSign, byte[] signingKey) throws Exception {

    byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signingKey);
    return Hex.encodeHexString(signature);
}



static byte[] HmacSHA256(String policy, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(policy.getBytes("UTF8"));
}



static byte[] getSigningKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}
```

If it helps, the signature that is given in the documentation is

> 46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9

while the signature I am able to get is

> 8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e

Comment: Is [this AWS Forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=831211&tstart=0) yours, too?  Or is this a coincidence?  It's interesting that you are getting a "wrong" result that [was formerly the "right" one](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119184742/http://docs.aws.amazon.com:80/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).

Comment: No that's not me, wow what a coincidence -  ! those are two amazing finds ! +1 for  actually digging out the archives ... :)  It is indeed very very strange that my correct result was a previously correct result.

Comment: Very strange, indeed.  I have a my own implementation of the V4 signing code, working for other purposes but not used for `POST` requests, which I am planning to test against these parameters and see what I come up with... I just haven't had an opportunity to do it, yet.

Comment: Thanks for that -I am beginning to believe it is a mistake in their documentation. I have now shifted to using presigned URLs because of this and that is very straightforward because SDK does the signature generation - I am unsure though about the pros and cons of the HTTP POST and presigned urls.