# Sample Amazon S3 POST object signature calculation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working off the Amazon [Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST Using AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) using code pretty much directly copied from [their Java v4 auth examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java). The signature I derive is not matching the signature they list in the examples. Using their general [test case](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-other) I am getting matching values for all intermediate keys. Is the signature displayed for the POST correct or did I miss something obvious?

```
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java
private static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
}

private static void printtHex(String msg, byte[] buffer) {
    String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(buffer).toLowerCase();
    System.out.format("%s: %s%n", msg, hex);
}

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java
private static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName,
                                      String serviceName, boolean debugIt)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
    if (debugIt)
        printtHex("kSecret", kSecret);
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    if (debugIt)
        printtHex("kDate", kDate);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    if (debugIt)
        printtHex("kRegion", kRegion);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    if (debugIt)
        printtHex("kService", kService);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    if (debugIt)
        printtHex("kSigning", kSigning);
    return kSigning;
}

public static void test() {
    try {
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html
        String expectedBase64Policy = "eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1LTEyLTMwVDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLA0KICAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJzaWd2NGV4YW1wbGVidWNrZXQifSwNCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRrZXkiLCAidXNlci91c2VyMS8iXSwNCiAgICB7ImFjbCI6ICJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LA0KICAgIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cDovL3NpZ3Y0ZXhhbXBsZWJ1Y2tldC5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3NmdWxfdXBsb2FkLmh0bWwifSwNCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCAiaW1hZ2UvIl0sDQogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXV1aWQiOiAiMTQzNjUxMjM2NTEyNzQifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LXNlcnZlci1zaWRlLWVuY3J5cHRpb24iOiAiQUVTMjU2In0sDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS10YWciLCAiIl0sDQoNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWNyZWRlbnRpYWwiOiAiQUtJQUlPU0ZPRE5ON0VYQU1QTEUvMjAxNTEyMjkvdXMtZWFzdC0xL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LA0KICAgIHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjogIkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiAiMjAxNTEyMjlUMDAwMDAwWiIgfQ0KICBdDQp9";
        String expectedSignature = "46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9";
        String secretKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";

        byte[] signingKey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, "20151229", "us-east-1", "s3", false);
        byte[] signedPolicy = HmacSHA256(expectedBase64Policy, signingKey);
        String calculatedSignature = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signedPolicy)
                .toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Generating signature for policy string for POST object");
        System.out.println("EXP: " + expectedSignature);
        System.out.println("GOT: " + calculatedSignature);

        // Test example from
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-other
        // intermediate keys match expected
        System.out.println("Generating signing for test example");
        getSignatureKey("wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY", "20120215", "us-east-1",
                        "iam", true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output I get:

```
Generating signature for policy string for POST object
EXP: 46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9
GOT: 8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
Generating signing for test example
kSecret: 41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559
kDate: 969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d
kRegion: 69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c
kService: f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa
kSigning: f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d
```

Comment: I haven't investigated this further, but there's something familiar looking about `8afdbf...` https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263367&tstart=0

Comment: Wow. Yes, I should've googled the signature I got. It looks like multiple people have struggled with the same issue and come up with the same result. I'm going to assume this is a doc bug unless somebody else can prove it wrong. In addition to the link you provided, some other examples include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109865/generating-an-aws-signature-v4-signature-for-uploading-to-s3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898464/signature-key-generation-for-aws-s3-http-post

Comment: Yeah, it's really odd. I suspect there's an explanation that could be backed into, potentially related to the policy document encoding -- did your policy base64 line up precisely with the example?  A stray `\r` or `\n` could throw that off.  For any given policy, there is only one correct signature, but that only applies to the base64(json()) of the policy.  Because the policy is a string in a serialization format that tolerates whitespace but is later treated as bytes by base64, you could have differing base64 for the policy, and a different signature, and still not be wrong.

Comment: I thought that may be the case too so I signed the base64 policy string also provided in the example which is what results in the 8afdbf... signature.